# Is it possible to receive streaming audio data from Twilio?

Tags: twilio, audio-streaming, twilio-api, twilio-php

Is it possible to receive streaming audio data from Twilio? I would like to be able to do this rather than simply downloading a recording after it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is not possible to receive streaming audio data from Twilio for a phone call. Your options are to wait for a recording, or if you are looking for voice recognition, you can try using [`<Gather>` with `input="speech"`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#input).

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has just announced [Streams](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream) ! It's a twiml verb that will communicate the audio through websockets to your server.

Otherwise you can try a solution I had worked on prior to their announcement: [twilio-client.js-recording-bot](https://github.com/nSimonFR/twilio-client.js-recording-bot)